# Why should one specify attribute values inside a constructor when it is simpler to specify them in the declaration?

Tags: java, constructor

I've just started learning about constructors and know that they're used to initialize objects. But i noticed that objects can be given initial values in the declaration (as in example 2) without having to specify them separately in a constructor.

Both examples below give the same result so what is the benefit of first declaring the attribute *and then* specifying the value in a constructor instead of right away in the declaration?

**Example 1:**

```
**public class Main {
    int x;  
    
    public Main() {
        x = 5;  
    }**

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main myObj = new Main();
        System.out.println(myObj.x);
    }
}
```

**Example 2:**

```
**public class Main {
    int x = 5;**

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main myObj = new Main();
        System.out.println(myObj.x);
    }
}
```

Comment: Suppose you have two variables and the value of the second one depends on the value of the first. You can't have that kind of logic outside a method or a constructor.

Comment: Google "java why constructor site:stackoverflow.com"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [what is the extra benefit of creating constructor in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17721316/what-is-the-extra-benefit-of-creating-constructor-in-java)

Comment: In your *particular* case, it doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, where you always want to set the value to a pre-defined value, a constructor is not required. It can be initialized at the time the attribute is defined. However, in most cases, it is not so simple - value of a class attribute is usually passed in at the time an instance is created. In such cases, a constructor is a good way to initialize the attributes of a class.

```
public class Main {
    int x;  
    
    public Main(int x) {
        this.x = x;  
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main myObj = new Main(6);
        System.out.println(myObj.x);
    }
}
```